# NFA for Alphabets in Matrix Form

Tags: automata, nfa

i want help with my assignment. I can understand this is not a place where you find someone to do your homework so i also tried other sites like CHEGG study with the same account info (telling you so it doesnt come in mind i am not trying)but still no one is able to help me out to get through it. So i thought after trying other options i should seek help here too. Again i can understand this is not a place where you get your assignment done but stil it is a place where i can find help that will make me able to understand the concepts. Please try your best to simplify things as i am really weak in this subject and dont have much time left now, a couple of hours left. I waster time on chegg study. I am uploading the picture
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 2: rename the four vectors a, b, c and d. Rules for valid patterns are as follows:

1. a must be followed by either a or c;
2. b must be followed by either a or c;
3. c must be followed by either b or d;
4. d must be followed by either b or d;
5. the string cannot start with b or d since those pull in 1 on the bottom

This suggests the following DFA:

```
 q  s  q'    q  s  q'    q  s q'     q  s q'     q  s q'     q  s q'
-- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --
q0  a qA    qA  a qA    qB  a qA    qC  a qX    qD  a qX    qX  a qX
q0  b qX    qA  b qX    qB  b qX    qC  b qB    qD  b qB    qX  b qX
q0  c qC    qA  c qC    qB  c qC    qC  c qX    qD  c qX    qX  c qX
q0  d qX    qA  d qX    qB  d qX    qC  d qD    qD  d qD    qX  d qX
```

In this DFA, all states qA, qB, qC and qD (and, optionally, q0) are accepting, and qX is not. qX is the dead state which gets visited once the DFA knows enough about the input to reject it.

Part 3: rename the vectors as in part 2. Rules for valid patterns are as follows:

1. all strings are made up of a whole number of chunks;
2. valid chunks are: aaa, aba, acc, adc, baa, bbb, bcc, bdd, cac, cbc, cca, cda, dac, dbd, dca, ddb.

An NFA for these looks like this:

```
 q  s  q'    q  s  q'    q  s  q'    q  s  q'    q  s  q'
-- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --
q0  a qA    qA  a qAA   qB  a qBA   qC  a qCA   qD  a qDA
q0  b qB    qA  b qAB   qB  b qBB   qC  b qCB   qD  b qDB
q0  c qC    qA  c qAC   qB  c qBC   qC  c qCC   qD  c qDC
q0  d qD    qA  d qAD   qB  d qBD   qC  d qCD   qD  d qDD

  q  s  q'     q  s  q'     q  s q'      q  s q'
--- -- --    --- -- --    --- -- --    --- -- --
qAA  a q0    qBA  a q0    qCA  c q0    qDA  c q0
qAB  a q0    qBB  b q0    qCB  c q0    qDB  d q0
qAC  c q0    qBC  c q0    qCC  a q0    qDC  a q0
qAD  c q0    qBD  d q0    qCD  a q0    qDD  b q0
```

Here, q0 is the accepting state (if the empty string is not to be accepted, create a new state q0' and only visit q0 once). Any transition not depicted indicates that the NFA crashes; this could be made into an equivalent DFA by filling in the missing transitions and having them go to a new dead state (like qX in the last example).